# How to delete records from a tables located on different servers?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I need to know how to delete records from different databases and different servers.

scenario:

I have 3 servers which contains 10 databases each server. The structure of the databases from the 3 servers are totally identical.

example: I need to delete the username from user table. the 3 servers have user table and the username I need to delete exists in the 3 servers (in user table to be specific).

Also, I need to have a condition or something like to check or validate whether that user exists on this database on this server.

All I know is to delete row from different databases using databasename.schema.tablename. my problem is how can I do it when the script I need to do needs to jump from different server.

any suggestions? or if you guys have different/better ideas, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the servers linked?

Comment: No. but the database inside those 3 servers are identical.

Comment: @Jerome Then run the DML on the 3 different instances.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have three servers `server1`, `server2` and `server3`. They all are in the same local network and they are visible to one another. And suppose you have a domain windows account under which you are now logged in and this account has a login on each server.

Then:

```
-- suppose you decided to delete users from table [user_table], 
-- located in databases (which are identical) called [user_database]  
-- on server1, server2 and server3 from server1.
USE master; --> server1
GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver N'server2', N'SQL Server';
GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver N'server3', N'SQL Server';
GO
-- after executing this statements server2 and server3 are linked to server1 -
-- this means that now you can execute queries against server2 and server3 from server1
-- it becomes possible because (as we supposed earlier) you have the domain windows 
-- account and linked servers by default is created with a security settings configured 
-- in a way that connections through them will be made under the current login's security
-- context - therefore you should be able to get access to the desired servers
-- (in SSMS from server1 check Object Explorer->server1->Server Objects->Linked Servers -
-- you should see server2 and server3 now)

-- ok, now you should be ready to execute DELETE statements against server1 (locally)
-- , server2 and server3 (through linked servers)
USE [user_database]; --> database on server1
GO

delete from user_table where username = 'user_name_you_want_to_delete';

delete from server2.[user_database].dbo.user_table 
where username = 'user_name_you_want_to_delete';

delete from server3.[user_database].dbo.user_table 
where username = 'user_name_you_want_to_delete';
```